# Automatic generation of html forms for database crud operations

Tags: java, html, database, web

I am looking for some framework in java which can directly create html forms from database tables for crud operations on DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) builds entities, pages and controllers based on Spring MVC,JPA. It can detect changes in the database. It is interesting that leaves no dependencies at runtime so, elements can be modified as regular Spring MVC elements, or you can add your own controllers, views, etc.

It has its limitations, of course, but it can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Would this work for you? http://incubator.apache.org/isis/index.html

Comment: thanks jim for your help, is there a framework which can be integrated with spring mvc?

Answer (score 4):

Telosys Tools (an Eclipse plugin) can generate a full Spring MVC web application 
from an existing database.

See the tutorials : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

( if necessary the templates are customizable )

Comment: This only generates basic  object classes for the database tables, but not HTML forms

Comment: Yes, it can generate HTML files, JSP files and so on. You just have to use the right templates.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Spring Roo can help you:

http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo

http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a big missing type framework in java. Roo works quite well, but it generates many files for each entity and seems to hava problems when you want to edit/remove some of them (at least it happened when I was trying). 
I would like something like django admin, it should generate the page dynamically for each entity, probably with a view class describing the view. 
For customizing a view even further it should follow a convention like:
views/domain/Entity.jsp -> replaces the whole view for the entity
views/domain/Entity_fieldname.jsp -> used as template for the field

Same thing for controllers, in roo there are many class that do almost the same thing. Why not use a default controller, and if the user defines a controller related to a entity, he could override the methods.

Of course this is not detailed enough, but I think pure java can improve a lot in making simple CRUD screens easy.
At least, this is the open source side. Inside business there are frameworks for CRUD, sometimes similara to this I describe. The hard part is making this framework decoupled from the other tools.

Answer (score 2):

**NetBeans** can generate JSF pages based on your entities to do basic CRUD operations.

How-To: [Generating a JavaServer Faces 2.x CRUD Application from a Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this:
[barahisolutions.com/code-generator.htm](http://www.barahisolutions.com/code-generator.htm)

Its a Swing based code generator to reverse engineer databases and  generate  HTML forms ,entities,daos.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a java based tool called Enfacade, that will generate CRUD screens from your DB tables.

The screens are data grid based and they will allow multiple grids to give one-to-many functionality.

You can then deploy to any java web application server using the runtime engine.