# What are admin UIs for spring-boot with mongoDB, providing CRUD operation like django-admin?

Tags: mongodb, user-interface, spring-boot, admin, database

I am implementing a new spring-boot application with mongoDB, earlier worked with djangoAdmin. Looking for a similar solution which can easily generate management UI for all classes decorated with @document.

Comment: Related: [Spring/Hibernate Entity Management Web Interface/UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4479828/5916915)

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen [**JHipster**](https://jhipster.github.io/)?

It uses an Angular frontend with a Spring Boot backend but comes with a ton of admin functionality right out of the box.  This includes the turn-key CRUD operations like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://lightadmin.org project. But it currently supports only Spring Data JPA.