# Spring web-based admin tool with CRUD

Tags: java, spring, admin, crud

In PHP & Symfony world there is a tool called Sonata Admin https://sonata-project.org/ based on AdminLTE template, that is all-in-one admin tool with login, menu configuration, and what is most important - database tables HTML grid CRUD generators.
The tool saves you tons of efforts by avoiding you writing boilerplate code, moreover, there might be a scenario that you would write zero code.

We need the same but for Java and Spring stack. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at JHipster project https://www.jhipster.tech/

With it you can create Spring Boot+Angular/React/Vue based applications. It provides some cool tools for generating CRUD entities by scaffolding.

Comment: You may check out https://bootify.io/frontend/spring-boot-admin-ui-with-crud.html - it generates CRUD views for your database based on Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example contains an example of how to create a Spring MVC CRUD there are plenty more examples of various spring project (This particular falls under Spring MVC).

This is not a ready-made CRUD, but a way how you could quickly implement one. 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/ is also worth checking.

Although there are few project like spring batch admin (For batch administration), or Spring boot admin (Monitoring spring boot applications), which provides a UI, mainly spring project provides a simple programmatically way of plugging in what's needed.

It's a plug & play kind of framework which targets various aspects of an enterprise application. Chances of finding a ready-made UI app would be more on GitHub rather than a specific spring plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to your question is No spring does not provide any tool for that but spring gives you the functionalities that can reduce your work but not with zero coding.

example:

- Using Spring Data JPA there is an Interface name curdRepository which 
  takes care of the curd Operations we dont need to implement the methods 
  for Curd Spring takes care of Curd operation.
- Spring Security Provides the login configuration with the login form and logout mechanism.

You can use spring boot or just visit the https://start.spring.io/ it will initialize the spring project with the dependencies you need

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started developing [Spring Boot Database Admin](https://github.com/aileftech/spring-boot-database-admin), which is a tool that does just what you ask. It's still in a very early stage though and it is not stable yet, but the main features are there.

Unlike Bootify, it doesn't generate code for you but you just include it as a JAR and everything is detected automatically (you do need to just make some minor configuration changes).